# Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry for key -- ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique not catching error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception

I am working on a rails app and have been getting the following error very often:

```
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '3022093-2000000028003-visited' for key 'unique_user_place_relationship'
```

While I've narrowed the source of the problem down to the following lines:

```
begin
  up = UserPlace.new(user_place_params)
  up.skip_logging
  up.save!
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
  Rails.logger.warn(e)
end
```

In my table, I have the following indices:

```
key_name                         seq_in_index    column_name
unique_user_place_relationship   1               user_id
unique_user_place_relationship   2               place_id
unique_user_place_relationship   3               relationship
```

**Is the problem that I don't have a `validate_uniqueness_of` user_id, place_id and relationship in my `user_place.rb`?**

From my understanding, `ActiveRecord:RecordNotUnique` should catch this error since the transaction does not meet the index constraints at the db level.

Comment: **Yes**, you should have the `validates_uniqueness_of` in place **in addition to** the database-level constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of-label-Concurrency+and+integrity) says:

> Using this validation method in conjunction with
>   `ActiveRecord::Validations#save` does not guarantee the absence of
>   duplicate record insertions, because `uniqueness` checks on the
>   application level are inherently prone to race conditions. For
>   example, suppose that two users try to post a Comment at the same
>   time, and a Comment’s title must be unique. At the database-level, the
>   actions performed by these users could be interleaved in the following
>   manner...

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what's the problem with adding `validates_uniqueness_of` but if you really don't want to use that and you are saying that the `rescue` isn't catching the exception, try removing `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e` all together and see if it catches the exception in that case.

Try something like the following:

```
rescue Exception => e
  if e.is_a? ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
    Rails.logger.warn(e)
  end
```